# Grid-разметка в IE11

Tags: css, вёрстка, internet-explorer, css-grid

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как мне изменить стили grid-разметки под IE11, во всех браузерах, кроме этого отображается корректно. Даже `gulp-autoprefixer` не спасает (не знаю в чем причина), в общем сам пример:

```css
.first-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.first-row .box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col0 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 50px;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 17px;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 17px;
}

.col3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 50px;
}

.second-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col4 {
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 17px;
}

.col5 {
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 17px;
}

.col6 {
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 17px;
}

.col7 {
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<section class="categories">
  <h2>Каталог товаров</h2>
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="box col0">
      <h2>
        <a href="">1</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col1">
      <h2>
        <a href="">2</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col2">
      <h2>
        <a href="">3</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col3">
      <h2>
        <a href="">4</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-row">

    <div class="box col4">
      <h2>
        <a href="">5</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col5">
      <h2>
        <a href="">6</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col6">
      <h2>
        <a href="">7</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col7">
      <h2>
        <a href="">8</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Интересует вопрос по префиксам, как правильно под IE11 записать, например, `grid-row: 1 / 3` или `grid-gap: 16px`, в документации не очевидно...

Comment: IE 11 имеет только частичную поддержку [display: grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20grid) (также как и display: flex). Префикс -ms-

Comment: @DiDex, вполне достаточную, но вот код надо переписать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Не добавляйте фиксированную высоту для самих клеток грида. Добавляйте высоту их детям.
2. К сожалению, автопрефиксов для гридов в `IE` будет недостаточно. И вообще, автопрефиксы бывают [разные](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers) с разной степенью качества и направленности, универсальных нет. Но выход есть, и это [миксины](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/RZpdaE).
3. А если понимать особенности гридов в `IE`, то можно и вручную:

```css
/**
 * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 
(https://meyerweb.com/
eric/tools/css/reset/)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

.first-row {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 16px 1fr 16px 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 16px 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.first-row .box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col0 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.col0 h2{ height: 50px;}

.col1 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.col1 h2{ height: 17px;}

.col2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.col2 h2{ height: 17px;}

.col3 {
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span:3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.col3 h2{ height: 50px;}

.second-row {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 16px 1fr 16px 1fr 16px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col4 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: auto;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.col4 h2{ height: 17px;}

.col5 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: auto;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.col5 h2{ height: 17px;}

.col6 {
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: auto;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.col6 h2{ height: 17px;}

.col7 {
  -ms-grid-column: 7;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: auto;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}
.col7 h2{ height: 17px;}
a{color:#fff}
```

```html
<section class="categories">
  <h2>Каталог товаров</h2>
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="box col0">
      <h2>
        <a href="">1</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col1">
      <h2>
        <a href="">2</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col2">
      <h2>
        <a href="">3</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col3">
      <h2>
        <a href="">4</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-row">

    <div class="box col4">
      <h2>
        <a href="">5</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col5">
      <h2>
        <a href="">6</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col6">
      <h2>
        <a href="">7</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col7">
      <h2>
        <a href="">8</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Особенность состоит в основном в том, что в ие нужно прописывать весть список колонок вместе с отступами - gap для ие не существует. То есть, если у вас ряд `1fr 1fr` с гапом в `16px`, то в ие это будет ряд `1fr 16px 1fr`. Соответственно место у второй колонки будет не второе, а третье. А ширину колонки(ряда) с ее местом тоже нужно писать в разных свойствах `-ms-grid-column-span` - ширина, `-ms-grid-column` - место колонки.

Comment: Ну вот зачем тащить reset в сниппет???

Comment: @Qwertiy пожалуй лучше было бы добавить отельным файлом, но добавила намеренно, чтобы было видно и понятно(а понятно не всем), что маргины и паддинги которые я добавляю, не имеют отношения к решению данной проблемы, цвет шрифта изменила для наглядности, какая колонка где(на моем эране еле заметны эти цифры)

Answer (score 2):

1. Нужны префиксы и IE требует явно прописывать ячейки грида.
2. IE не поддерживает `grid-gap` - вместо него надо использовать лишние пустые ячейки.
3. Вместо высоты лучше указывать высоту рядов.
4. Для объединения ячеек надо использовать `span` в соответствующем виде.

Вот для первой строки, для второй аналогично: https://jsfiddle.net/ntv0n8s1/1/

```css
.first-row {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 16px 1fr 16px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 17px 16px 17px;
  grid-template-rows: 17px 17px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.col0 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.col1 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.col2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.col3 {
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
  grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="categories">
  <h2>Каталог товаров</h2>
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="box col0">
      <h2>
        <a href="">1</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col1">
      <h2>
        <a href="">2</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col2">
      <h2>
        <a href="">3</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box col3">
      <h2>
        <a href="">4</a>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Дополню: IE кладёт все элементы grid-контейнера в самую первую ячейку, то есть значения `-ms-grid-column: 1` и `-ms-grid-row: 1` для каждой ячейки в IE стоят по умолчанию, поэтому такие строки CSS можно опустить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, верно. Но проще указать, по-моему.